# How do I display two logos on my Squarespace site?

Tags: squarespace

I'm trying to find code that will allow me to place two logos on my squarespace site—one logo in the top left and one in the top right. See photo example below. Ideally, the two logos will each link to a specific page as well.

[image: screenshot example]

Comment: What template are you using?

Comment: @Brandon I am using "Wav"